# Internal logic of operator [] when dealing with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I've been studying C++ for couple of months now and just recently decided to look more deeply into the logic of pointers and arrays. What I've been taught in uni is pretty basic - pointers contain the address of a variable. When an array is created, basically a pointer to its first element is created.

So I started experimenting a bit. (and got to a conclusion which I need confirmation for). First of all I created

```
int arr[10];
int* ptr = &arr[5];
```

And as you would imagine

```
cout << ptr[3];
```

gave me the 8th element of the array. Next I tried

```
int num = 6;
int* ptr2 = &num;
cout << ptr2[5];
cout << ptr2 + 5;
```

which to my great delight (not irony) returned the same addresses. Even though num wasn't an array.

The conclusion to which I got: array is not something special in C++. It's just a pointer to the first element (already typed that). More important: Can I think about every pointer in the manner of object of a `class variable*`. Is the `operator []` just overloaded in the `class int*`? For example to be something along the lines of:

```
int operator[] (int index){
    return *(arrayFirstaddress + index);
}
```

What was interesting to me in these experiments is that `operator []` works for EVERY pointer. (So it's exactly like overloading an operator for all instances of the said class)

Of course, I can be as wrong as possible. I couldn't find much information in the web, since I didn't know how to word my question so I decided to ask here.
It would be extremely helpful if you explained to me if I'm right/wrong/very wrong and why.

Comment: `ptr2[5]` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds. For purposes of pointer arithmetic, `&num` points to an array of exactly one element.

Comment: `a[b]` is explicitly translated to `*(a + b)`

Comment: Curious fact: `3[ptr]` is valid and means the same thing as `ptr[3]`. As @Fureeish notes, `a[b]` is by definition equivalent to `*(a + b)`. This latter form is symmetrical wrt `a` and `b`, even if the original is not.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I know it's undefined behaviour, but what's in that blcok of memory doesn't really concern me. More like the fact that the compiler does not care if it's part of the array boundaries or not (Or if it is a part of array for that matter.) what I mean is that as Fureeish said int* a[b] == *(a + b), which was pretty much my discovery / question. Also as a bonus is there any place where I can see the actual code for the creation of C++

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the actual code for the creation of C++". If you want to see disassembly of your C++ program, your C++ compiler of choice probably has an option to emit it; or you could play around at https://godbolt.org/ . If you mean the source code of a C++ compiler, there is a bunch of open-source ones you could study.

Comment: *"The conclusion to which I got: array is not something special in C++. It's just a pointer to the first element."* -- completely wrong. An array is a data structure that holds one or more items of the same type in consecutive locations in memory. The **array name** is a pointer to its first element and can be used anywhere a pointer can be used but the reverse doesn't happen. A pointer is not an array and it doesn't resemble an array in any way. A pointer is a variable that doesn't store a value but the address in memory of another object (be it a variable or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find the definition of subscripting, i.e. an expression like `ptr2[5]` in the c++ standard, e.g. like in [this online c++ draft standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.sub#1):

> 5.2.1 Subscripting [expr.sub]
>
> (1) ...  The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to
>   *((E1)+(E2))

So your "discovery" sounds correct, although your examples seem to have some bugs (e.g. `ptr2[5]` should not return an address but an int value, whereas `ptr2+5` is an address an not an int value; I suppose you meant `&ptr2[5]`).

Further, your code is not a prove of this discovery as it is based on undefined behaviour. It *may* yield something that supports your "discovery", but your discovery could still be not valid, and it could also do the opposite (really!).

The reason why it is undefined behaviour is that even [pointer arithmetics](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.add#6) like `ptr2+5` is undefined behaviour if the result is out of the range of the allocated memory block `ptr2` points to (which is definitely the case in your example):

> 5.7 Additive operators
>
> (6) ... Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array
>   object, or one past the last element of the array object, the behavior
>   is undefined.

Different compilers, different optimization settings, and even slight modifications anywhere in your program may let the compiler do other things here.

Answer (score 2):

An array in C++ is a collection of objects.  A pointer is a variable that can store the address of something.   The two are not the same thing.

Unfortunately, your sample

> ```
> int num = 6;
> int* ptr2 = &num;
> cout << ptr2[5];
> cout << ptr2 + 5;
> ```

exhibits undefined behaviour, both in the evaluation of `ptr2[5]` and `ptr2 + 5`.    Pointer expressions are special - arithmetic involving pointers only has defined behaviour if the pointer being acted on (`ptr2` in this case) and the result (`ptr2 + 5`) are within the same object.   Or one past the end (although dereferencing a "one past the end" pointer - trying to access the value it points at - also gives undefined behaviour).

Semantically, `*(ptr + n)` and `ptr[n]` are equivalent (i.e. they have the same meaning) if `ptr` is a pointer and `n` is an integral value.  So if evaluating `ptr + n` gives undefined behaviour, so does evaluating `ptr[n]`.     Similarly, `&ptr[n]` and `ptr + n` are equivalent.

In expressions, depending on context, the name of an array is *converted to* a pointer, and that pointer is equal to the address of that array's first element.   So, given

```
  int x[5];
  int *p;
     // the following all have the same effect

  p = x + 2;
  p = &x[0] + 2;
  p = &x[2];
```

That does not mean an array is a pointer though.